# $R_{a} = R[x]/(x)$ isomorphic to $R_{b} = R[x]/(x-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I am looking at the following two rings:

$R_{a} = R[x]/(x)$ and  $R_{b} = R[x]/(x-1)$.

I was told that these two rings were isomorphic, but I don't see why. Is this due to the minimal polynomials?

Comment: Both are isomorphic to $R$. For example, the map $R[x]/(x) \to R$ given by $f \mapsto f(0)$ is an isomorphism, and similarly for the map $R[x]/(x-1) \to R$ given by $f \mapsto f(1)$. (First check that these two maps are well-defined.)

Comment: So then $R[x]/(x^2 )$ would not be isomorphic to $R_a$ or $R_b$ because that is not isomorphic to $R$?

Comment: Right, $R[x]/(x^2)$ is not isomorphic to $R$ as $R$-algebra, since they're not even isomorphic as $R$-modules. Note that the question whether they are isomorphic as abstract rings (without the $R$-algebra structure) is much more subtle (the answer might depend on the ring $R$).

Comment: Thank you! Also, is $R[x]/(x-1)$ isomorphic to $R[x]/(x^2-1)$ because we can factor x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1), right? And how would you find an isomorphism between $R[x]/(x-a)$ and $R$ in general? Just send $f$ to $f(a)$?

Comment: Since $x^2 - 1 = (x-1)(x+1)$, the Chinese Remainder Theorem says the ring $R[x]/(x^2-1)$ is isomorphic to $R/(x-1) \times R/(x+1) = R \times R$ (but *not* isomorphic to $R$). And indeed, the map $R[x]/(x-a) \to R$ given by $f \mapsto f(a)$ is an isomorphism.