# Properties of a new imaginary number?

Tags: complex-numbers

Everyone knows the imaginary number $i$ and it's interesting properties like $i^2=-1$.

Hypothetical:

What would some properties be of a number $I$ such that $\sqrt{I}=-1$? (it's principle square root being -1) For example, could we determain some simple powers of $I$?

*And yes, I know such a number doesn't exist.*

Edit: Suppose we add an axiom to this question banning the deduction of the value of $I$. I'm interested in what other properties and quirks one can deduce from this number, not how contradictory it is.

Comment: Huh?  That just means $I=(-1)^2$.  Such a number must certainly *does* exist.

Comment: @fleablood True, though to clarify I was referring to it's principle square root being -1. In which, no complex number holds a property of that type.

Comment: *How* do you define principal square root?

Comment: Well, it's trivial to point out that it's arbitrary to define "principal" root as the positive one.  This question is no more significant or meaningful then asking what characteristic a right handed person whose dominate hand is his left would have. Or what a square circle would be like.  Its meaning is solely arbitrary, and you are are simply  picking a contradictory term.

Comment: @fleablood Are you sure?? Let $z=re^{i\phi}$ with $-\pi<\phi\le \pi$ and $r\ge0$, then $\sqrt z$ (the principle value) is defined as $\sqrt z=\sqrt r e^{\frac{i\phi} 2}$, that is, it is defined using the nonpositive real axis as a branch cut.

Comment: Wong Austin.  So what?  That's a completely arbitrary definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general when we invent new numbers we also try to preserve some algebraic structure along with the process of defining addition and multiplication in the new ring created.

One possible construction is to take the quotient of the field of polynomials by an irreducible polynomial.

For instance if we take the complex numbers $\mathbb C$, we have $i^2=-1$ so $i$ is solution of the equation $X^2+1=0$.

The theory of abstract algebras says then that $\mathbb R[X]\big/(X^2+1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ as constructed directly via $z=x+iy$ and the addition and multiplication formulas.

Following this principle some exotic algebras were also constructed, for instance the field of hyperbolic complexes or split-complexes on the model of $\mathbb R[X]\big/(X^2-1)$

$\to\ $[Wikipedia : split-complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number)

This time we define a new number $j$ that verifies $j^2=1$ without being nor $1$ nor $-1$ and $z=x+jy$ as in the *standard* case.

Knowing this we could dig up your idea: what if we define $I$ such that $\sqrt{I}=-1$?

The issue is that our theory doesn't apply since $\sqrt{X}+1$ is not a polynomial.

And if we reduce it to $I=(-1)^2=1$, thus $I$ being an abstract root $X-1$,then $\mathbb R[X]\big/(X-1)$ is simply isomorphic to plain $\mathbb R$, so we are not much more advanced.

$\to\ $ [$R_{a} = R[x]/(x)$ isomorphic to $R_{b} = R[x]/(x-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773560/r-a-rx-x-isomorphic-to-r-b-rx-x-1)

It doesn't mean it is impossible to make anything out of $\sqrt{I}=-1$, but you still have to invent and define coherent algebraic rules that would give the abstract algebra based on $I$ some interesting properties.

Comment: Very interesting! I've not heard of split-complex numbers and I'll definitely have a look.

Answer (score 3):

It's tricky to answer this question sensibly. As fleablood observed, the fact that $I$ has a square root (principle or not) $-1$ implies that $I = (-1)^2 = 1$. Then, the principle square root, a somewhat arbitrary choice between the two possible square roots, is positive by convention. So for this hypothetical, I think we're being asked to break convention.

So, I think we need to expand the space a little, to allow this hypothetical to be meaningful. Hopefully you know about the polar form of complex numbers: every complex number can be expressed (not uniquely) in the form $r e^{i\theta}$, where $r \ge 0$ is the modulus (distance from the origin) and $\theta$ is the argument (angle between positive real axis and the line segment from $0$ to the complex number. So, we can express any given complex number as ordered pairs $(r, \theta)$, where $r$ is unique, and $\theta$ can take infinitely many values.

My idea is to make each point $(r, \theta)$ unique, so that $(r, \theta) \neq (r, \theta + 2\pi)$. We can define multiplication as per De Moivre's Theorem, i.e.
$$(r, \theta)(s, \gamma) = (rs, \theta + \gamma).$$
We would therefore have $(r, \theta)^2 = (r^2, 2\theta)$ which, importantly, implies that each number in this space has **only one square root**. The points $(1, 0)$ and $(1, 2\pi)$ both represent $1$ in this space, but $\sqrt{(1, 2\pi)} = (1, \pi)$ which is $-1$ in the complex numbers, whereas $\sqrt{(1, 0)} = (1, 0)$, which is $1$ in the complex numbers.

Of course, it also means that all $n$-th roots will be unique as well, something that definitely does not hold in $\mathbb{C}$.

It's also not that easy to define a space. I haven't talked about addition on this space of $[0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R}$. We would want it to be a commutative group, and have multiplication distribute over it. I haven't worked out the details, so I'm not even sure it's possible. Another important feature of $\mathbb{C}$ is its topology, so it would be good if there would be some compatible topology on this space as well.

But anyway, I guess it's food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting idea, but there's a conflict of definitions that make such a number impossible - not just because there is no such number, but because the concept of "number" can't be expanded to include it. The main issue is that the definition of the *principal square root* of a number $x$ is *that non-negative number $y$ so that $y^2 = x$*. In order to claim that $-1$ is the principal square root of something, you have to *also* claim that $-1$ is non-negative - this is a lot like saying "What if Bob got married, but was still a bachelor?" A person can't be both married and a bachelor, not just because there are no such people, but because the meanings of the words prevent them from applying to the same person.

If you can define "principal square root" without referring to the root's position within an existing number system (e.g., the reals or the complex numbers), this problem disappears; but no such definition exists.

Comment: Very true. But still, giving a number's square root to be -1 also means we can determinate it's 4th root to be $i$. Never minding it's impossibility of having a sole value.

Comment: @Graviton We can also deduce that $I$ is equal to $1$, since by definition we have that $(\sqrt{x})^2 = x$ for all $x$. Since the principal fourth root of $1$ is $1$, we can now conclude that $i$ (the principal fourth root of $I$, as you said) is equal to $1$. Deducing facts about a contradictory object never produces anything helpful - you just get more contradictions.